# semgrep - any way to strip out terminal codes in its default output?

Tags: format, output, semgrep

If I run semgrep on the command line, I get a very nice output.

[image]

However, if I save to a file, I get all sorts of terminal ANSI escape sequences when I open it in a text editor:

```
Findings:

[36m[22m[24m  ....lib/_baseutils.py [0m
     [1m[24mpython.flask.security.xss.audit.direct-use-of-jinja2.direct-use-of-jinja2[0m
        Detected direct use of jinja2. If not done properly, this may bypass HTML escaping which
        opens up the application to cross-site scripting (XSS) vulnerabilities. Prefer using the
        Flask method 'render_template()' and templates with a '.html' extension in order to
        prevent XSS.
        Details: https://sg.run/RoKe

       2252┆ templateEnv = [1m[24mEnvironment(loader=templateLoader)[0m
          ⋮┆----------------------------------------
```

Yes, I know I can `cat out.txt` and it looks beautiful again.  But how do I get a format that looks ok in a text editor?  (Actually, the best would be a markdown, since the urls would work).

Now, I've tested `--json` flag, but that's over complicated for human readability.  `--vim`, `--emacs` was ok, but a bit terse, like missing the rules urls.  And too long being in a single line.  The rest of the output formats like `--junit` look even lesss promising.

I *guess* I could `sed` the output to strip out those terminal characters.  Any other ideas to look at?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the normal terminal printout is what you want you can use the fact that `semgrep` [supports](https://semgrep.dev/docs/release-notes/#changes-7) the [somewhat standard `NO_COLOR` environment variable](https://no-color.org/). So running:

```
env NO_COLOR=1 semgrep <command> > <file>
```

should get you a file sans-ANSI escape sequences.